# Pygame working on idle but not on pycharm

Tags: python

I installed pygame wheel file and run with command prompt. Now, when I type import pygame in idle pygame works but not on pycharm.any solutions?

Comment: You must be [much more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually install it onto PyCharm. Go to File then Settings then Project Interpreter, and then click the green plus sign and type pygame. Then import it there.

Refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKzfNBTRx5U) if there is any issues.